# Found this but unsure how to call so i can go

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

How do i use this function properly i found it on stack without instructions

i declared it as      `var db = DeepCopy(absenceEntity);`
but how do i access the properties within absenceEntity so I can show the orignal values.

I am trying to implment a copy of values to store before savechanges is called is their an easier way to do this its for audit tracking

```
public static object DeepCopy(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    Type type = obj.GetType();

    if (type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string))
    {
        return obj;
    }
    else if (type.IsArray)
    {
        Type elementType = Type.GetType(type.FullName.Replace("[]", string.Empty));
        var array = obj as Array;
        Array copied = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, array.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            copied.SetValue(DeepCopy(array.GetValue(i)), i);
        }
        return Convert.ChangeType(copied, obj.GetType());
    }
    else if (type.IsClass)
    {
        object toret = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            object fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);
            if (fieldValue == null)
                continue;
            field.SetValue(toret, DeepCopy(fieldValue));
        }
        return toret;
    }
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type");
}
```

Comment: Isn't `absenceEntity` what you passed to the method?

Comment: yes its the orignal entity object to which i want to make the copy of  private EmployeeAbsence absenceEntity how do i then access the copied version ? @Gildor

Comment: It will be returned by the method call.

Comment: yes but when i call it as   var db = DeepCopy(absenceEntity); and try to access a property of the absenceEntity ie db.reason which is a field of abesnentity it doesnt appear in intellscene ? @Arkiliknam

Comment: The method returns an `object` if you want to access specific type fields, you need to cast it first to the type of whatever `absenceEntity` is.

Comment: @Arkiliknam what is the best way of doing a clone in .EF 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either access the properties on absenceEntity before passing it in or simply

```
var _absenceEntity = DeepCopy(absenceEntity);
```

and then

```
_absenceEntity.(specify propperty here)
```

Comment: I am trying to implment audit tracking in EF 4.0 what is best way to get oringal values from entity after saved changes been called

Comment: @DavidB You should put that requirement in the question so that others can understand much easier.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with audit tracking in EF 4.0 , how is this   related to the main SO question?